# Use value of form control in a new record

Tags: ms-access-2013

Microsoft Access 2013 form with a value named FullSiteData built from this expression:

```
="50" & "-" & [IslandCode] & "-" & [QuadData] & "-" & [SiteData]
```

where IslandCode is a combobox and QuadData and SiteData are validated textboxes.

My question is how do I save the result of the expression into the Access table?

A textbox with data Control Source linked to the table field works, but I'd like to use the result of the expression builder instead.

I've built some web forms using PHP and MySQL and understand the process of a query adding data to a table, but don't really understand what Access is doing.  Should I be looking at using the event properties?

Comment: Are you also saving [IslandCode], [QuadData], and [SiteData] to the table as separate fields?

Comment: Aloha and thank you - currently I'm not but based on the advice on two other forums I'm looking at doing that.  This is a legacy table that has 20k records and already stores the string I'm building as a single field - and much of the data needs to edited.  And with a May deadline I need to get version 1 up and running without too many changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a matter of just *adding* new records to the database then you could use a Text Box bound to [FullSiteData] and have the `After Update` events of the controls for the constituent parts (Combo Box and two Text Boxes) update the `.Value` of the [FullSiteData] Text Box. When the record is saved that `.Value` will be written to the [FullSiteData] field.

If you will also be *editing* existing records then things get more messy because in the `On Current` event you'd have to split the existing [FullSiteData] into its parts and then set the values of the other controls to match. (Not so bad for the Text Boxes, but doing that for the Combo Box could be a bit of a nuisance.)

If the latter is a possibility then I recommend that you "bite the bullet", split the existing [FullSiteData] values into separate fields, and save those fields separately. Then you could convert [FullSiteData] to a Calculated field in the table (using the expression in your question) to minimize the impact on existing reports, etc.. (My guess is that most of them probably won't even notice...)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have decided to split the add and edit between different forms and users so this is promising!  Thanks again, Alan